# Динамическое создание контролов на другом контроле

Tags: c++, c++builder, controls

Пытаюсь динамически создавать контролы на другом контроле, но они никак не отображаются. Хотя сам контрол визуально существует (проверял через установку цвета контрола в черный). Что я упускаю при их динамическом создании?

```
class tev : public TCustomControl {
private:
    TButton* button;

public:
    __fastcall tev(TComponent* Owner) : TCustomControl(Owner) {
        Parent = (TWinControl*)Owner;
        Left = 100;
        Top = 100;
        Width = 200;
        Height = 200;
        button = new TButton(this);
        button->Height = 100;
        button->Width = 100;
        button->Left = 100;
        button->Top = 100;
        Color = clBlack;
    }

    virtual __fastcall ~tev() {
        delete button;
    }
};

tev* t;

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
   t = new tev(Form1);
   t->Parent = this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После создания компонента, необходимо было назначить свойство Parent.

```
button = new TButton(this);
button->Parent = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cвойство `Visible` класса `TWinControl` определяет отображаемость компонента. Следует добавить в конструктор:

```
button->Visible = true;
```

Comment: Visible по-умолчанию установлен в true (__property Visible = {default=1};). Не помогло.

Comment: После создания окна функцией `CreateWindow` нужно всегда вызвать `ShowWindow`, чтобы оно появилось на экране.

Comment: совсем не туда ушли